# How to access to model three on mobile or tablette?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm trying to list some elements of my building by accessing to the Three of my model.

It's working very fine on my computer but not on my Ipad or Tablet.

I'm  using  this code :

```
    getInstanceTree() {

    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        let viewer = LevelsExtension.viewer;
        viewer.getObjectTree(function (instanceTree) {
          return resolve(instanceTree);
        },
          function (errorCode) {
            return reject(errorCode);
          });

      } catch (ex) {
        return reject(ex)
      }
    })
  };
```

On mobile and Ipad,  `return reject(errorCode);` is call with `undefined` value in the `errorCode`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An error callback with no error code might indicate that the model database (where the object tree is stored) is not yet available. At what point are you calling the `getInstanceTree()` method?

The viewer triggers an event when the model database is ready - you can subscribe to it using `viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT, function(ev) { ... })`.

Hope that helps :)

EDIT: following up on our discussion on the [gist](https://gist.github.com/petrbroz/afe9ef25b79d78dc1d9099714b22592c), and for anyone running into similar problems:

When you're unable to access the object tree of a model on a mobile device, you're likely hitting memory limits of the Forge viewer, and you can try to bypass those by explicitly setting the limits to zero:

```
viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(
    document.getElementById('viewer'),
    { memory: { limit: 0 } }
);
```

Comment: I'm already listening `Autodesk.Viewing.OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT` but it look it never firing on mobile. I've try with `VIEWER_INITIALIZED`, `MODEL_LAYERS_LOADED_EVENT` etc.

Comment: I put together a quick [example](https://gist.github.com/petrbroz/afe9ef25b79d78dc1d9099714b22592c), tested it on an iPhone 6S, and the `OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT` event triggered as expected. Do you subscribe to the event as soon as the viewer is instantiated?

Comment: I've try your code and I do not have any `alert`... and no error in the console.

Comment: I've post a comment and a link in your Git Code.

Comment: When you say 'explicitly setting limits to zero', what exactly does this do? There isn't any documentation on the config for  new GuiViewer3D(container,config) found here: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/reference/javascript/guiviewer3d/

Comment: Setting the limit to zero effectively means "do not apply any memory limit to the model being loaded". This can however cause the browser tab to crash, which is why the config option is not exposed in the documentation.