# Search in model browser disabled on mobile

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I was wondering if its possible to enable the search in the model browser on mobile devices. Or is there a specific reason its not visible on mobile.

I noticed that in the code you check if the viewer is loaded on mobile to determine if it will show it or not. But I could not figure out to enable it with the API or something.

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51909038/how-to-access-to-model-three-on-mobile-or-tablette/51926542#51926542. Does that answer your question?

Comment: It doesn't answer my question. Im aware that we could use that to build our own search but I would like to use the search function of the model browser that is already present on mobile devices.

Comment: I see. I'm not sure why the search UI is disabled, since the [search API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/viewer3d/#search-text-onsuccesscallback-onerrorcallback-attributenames) itself is available. There's no official API to re-enable the searchbar, but you could try working around it by modifying the `Autodesk.Viewing.isMobileDevice` function before the UI is initialized.

Comment: Although that could be a way to go by it, it would also mean it disables this check on other places where I might want to retain mobile functionality (like mobile speed optimalisations)

Comment: True, it would be quite hacky and could potentially affect the overall behavior significantly... I've done a bit more research and found a more reasonable workaround. Let me post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the [search API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/viewer3d/#search-text-onsuccesscallback-onerrorcallback-attributenames) is available even on mobile devices, you're correct that the search UI is explicitly hidden. If you want to work around it, you can try using the viewer's [setModelStructurePanel](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/guiviewer3d/#setmodelstructurepanel-modelstructurepanel) method (right after the viewer is instantiated) and pass it your own instance of `ViewerModelStructurePanel` with the search field explicitly set to be visible:

```
const ave = Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions;
const viewer = viewerApp.myCurrentViewer;
const options = {
    docStructureConfig: viewer.config.docStructureConfig,
    hideSearch: false,
    excludeRoot: viewer.config.modelBrowserExcludeRoot,
    startCollapsed: viewer.config.modelBrowserStartCollapsed
};
viewer.setModelStructurePanel(new ave.ViewerModelStructurePanel(viewer, 'My Title', options));
```

Comment: I'm glad to hear that :) Cheers!